# My code is returning null somehow, I have no idea why

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am creating a maze generator as a side project for fun, and I am running into an issue where

```
newTile.getxCoord()
```

is creating a null pointer exception, and I have no idea why. I checked to ensure the creation of my "tile" is using positive values that exist within the bounds of my board.

Here is the link to the method and code as a whole https://github.com/Dibes/Maze/blob/master/src/MazeCreation/DepthFirst.java#L30.

For a quick walk through of my thought process for this code

```
// Set the starting tile as visited and current
    TileGenerator.setTileVisible(Maze.startingTile.getxCoord(), Maze.startingTile.getyCoord(), 0);
// Set the starting tile as the current tile
    TileGenerator.setTileCurrent(Maze.startingTile.getxCoord(), Maze.startingTile.getyCoord(), 1);
    // Set the last tile as the starting tile
    Tile lastTile = Maze.startingTile;
    // Grab a new tile that is within the bounds of the map and is greater than 0
    Tile newTile = TileGenerator.getTile(Utility.getHorizNext(lastTile.getxCoord(), -1, 1), Utility.getVertNext(lastTile.getyCoord(), -1, 1));
    while(!TileGenerator.isTilesVisited()) {
        // Debug testing
        if (newTile.getxCoord() < 0 || newTile.getyCoord() < 0) {
            System.out.println(newTile.getxCoord() + " " + newTile.getyCoord());
        }
        // Set the current tile visible
        TileGenerator.setTileVisible(newTile.getxCoord(), newTile.getyCoord(), 0);
        // Set the last tile marked as not current
        TileGenerator.setTileCurrent(lastTile.getxCoord(), lastTile.getyCoord(), 0);
        // Set the newly found tile marked as current (shows up as red on the board)
        TileGenerator.setTileCurrent(newTile.getxCoord(), newTile.getyCoord(), 1);
        // Grab new tile
        lastTile = newTile;
        newTile = TileGenerator.getTile(Utility.getHorizNext(lastTile.getxCoord(), -1, 1), Utility.getVertNext(lastTile.getyCoord(), -1, 1));
        // A sleep in the thread so i could see the generation slowly
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Sorry for being brief, I just am not sure why it would be creating a null pointer.

Comment: Please post the relevant code instead of posting a link.

Comment: Either `newTile` is null, or something under `getxCoord()` is null. Look at your stack trace to determine which.

Comment: You don't check if `getTile` returns NULL. Are you sure it cannot fail?

Comment: @Jongware I totally didn't do a null check on that >.> thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newTile` is created by `TileGenerator.getTile()` - According to the source for `TileGenerator`, this method can return a null instance:

https://github.com/Dibes/Maze/blob/master/src/Components/TileGenerator.java#L78

```
public static Tile getTile(int xCoord, int yCoord) {
    for (int[] tile : mapTiles) {
        if (tile[Tile.XCOORD] == xCoord && tile[Tile.YCOORD] == yCoord) {
            return new Tile(tile[Tile.XCOORD], tile[Tile.YCOORD], tile[Tile.XLOC], tile[Tile.YLOC], tile[Tile.ISFILLED], tile[Tile.ISVISITED], tile[Tile.ISCURRENT]);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Your code is producing a `NullPointerException` because the tile is null - have you written a unit test which covers the case that you're working with?

Comment: That is exactly what the issue was! Thanks! I'll set it as the answer soon

Comment: More importantly than finding the bug is ensuring that it doesn't happen again in the future with a good suite of unit tests.  You might also want to revisit the `getTile` method in `TileGenerator`.  Does it make sense to return `null` as a fallback value?  Would an exception make more sense here?

Comment: I think null makes sense in this case simply because it cannot reach a tile at that point, so the tile is null. If I throw an exception it interrupts the flow of the program where I would rather just continue on and correct the coordinates, rather than stop it completely. But I agree that I should think more on the matter when it comes to the rest of the program!